# jmeter: Error invoking bsh method: eval

Tags: eval, runtime-error, jmeter

When i try to execute the following code in jmeter:

```
import org.json.JSONArray; 
import org.json.JSONObject;
String jsonString = prev . . . ''
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of:
import org.json.JSONArray; import org.json.JSONObject; String jsonString = prev
 : Typed variable declaration : Object constructor 

script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject; 

    String jsonString = prev . . . '' :
    Typed variable declaration :
     Object constructor
```

I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Can you please show your whole code.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It's not clear from the question...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I guess you put the BeanShell Processor in wrong place. Your BeanSheel Processor must be under the HTTP Request, not at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong:

> prev . . . ''

It should be java code compatible with jdk1.4

You have option to use Jsr223 + groovy but anyway your code is wrong